# Cannot add or update NuGet packages, receiving NuGet V2 feed error

Tags: jquery, nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019

I have recently moved to VS 2019 and now I can not install or update packages through NuGet. I receive the following error -

> An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'jQuery.3.4.1' from source 'NuGet.org'.
>   Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at 'https://www.nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='jQuery'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' with following message : Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
>   Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).

I have NuGet Package source pointing to ---   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Is there another package source I should be using?

Comment: Hi friend, which install/update way do you use when you meet this issue? In cmd.exe, package manager console or Nuget Package Manager UI?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**If you meet this issue in VS IDE:**

Go `Tools=>Nuget Package Manager=>Package Manager Settings=>Package Source` to check if you have other package source whose URL is `https://www.nuget.org`, if it exists, disable/delete this package source.

**If you meet this issue in command line:**

[image]

You need to specify the source like this: `nuget install PackageName -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -Version 3.4.1`. You may use other install command(dotnet other what), just make sure you specify the correct source in command.

Hope it helps to give a correct direction to resolve the issue :)

Comment: thank you -I did have another packet sources with the nuget.org url. Once I removed it, I am able to make updates.

Comment: To me, this is a bug with the NuGet manager.  For my case with EF Tools, the package has the source declared, but the manager is still allowing my alternatice source to be included in the process.  So, What's the "All" setting for?

Answer (score 4):

In VS Package Sources, I had something like http://api.nuget.org
I replaced that with **https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json**
and that fixed it. (Putting the explicit version number on  the end did not work.)

Comment: Thanks, Tom.  `index.json` was the missing piece of my puzzle when moving from an old v2 proxy to a new v3.  My head is quite sore from banging it on the desk, but it'll heal in time.